# How do you find z from $|z+\bar z| + |z-\bar z| = 2z +6$

Tags: complex-numbers

How do you find the complex number $z$ from the length?

I have tried substituting $z= x+iy$ into the equation and I end up with

> $2x + 2y = 2x + 2iy +6$

This doesn't make sense if I equate $2x +2y$ with the real part $2x +6$ as this leaves $2iy$ hanging.

I have looked up the properties of the complex number and there does not seem to have a theorem based on this.

Comment: The left hand side contains two real numbers so $z$ can't have any imaginary part, thus $z=\bar z$ and $z+\bar z=2z$. Are you sure you transcribed the question correctly?

Comment: @SuzuHirose yes, its a question i received from my lecturer

Comment: It's just $|2z|=2z+6$ then , and if $2z=|2z|$ that doesn't have any solution, so it must be that $z=-1.5$ without any imaginary part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you get $|2x|+|2iy|=2x+2iy+6$. Since the left side  is real we must have $y=0$. So $|2x|=2x+6$ which gives $x=-3/2$.

Comment: No the right side is $2z$ so there is no solution unless $z$ is negative.

Comment: @SuzuHirose You are right. Thank you.

Comment: @geetha290krm may I ask why are you treating |2x| = 2x +6 as -2x = 2x+6  ? Isnt "| |" in complex term to find the length ?

Comment: $|x+iy|=\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}$ for $x$ and $y$ real. But when  $y=0$ this becomes $|x|$, the usual absolute value of $x$. You are probably making the mistake of thinking that $\sqrt {x^{2}}=x$ but $\sqrt {x^{2}}=|x|$.  @Shreamy

Comment: @geetha290krm thanks